# Batch execution is not happening for deletion operation

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to delete rows from the database as a Batch update operation. I have written the below method to accomplish the task but when i execute, It does not delete the entries from the table. So the table remains the same.
Please let me know if there is any bug in the code.

```
public void removeFromDb(String partnerId, List<String> packagedServiceIdList) throws CustomException {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(REMOVE_DATA_MAP);
        for(int i=0; i<packagedServiceIdList.size();i++) {

            ps.setString(1, partnerId);
            ps.setString(2, packagedServiceIdList.get(i));
            ps.addBatch();
            gLogger.debug("query is: "+ps.toString());
        }
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        gLogger.error("Exception while removing the record from table, SQLException:{}", sqle);
        throw new CustomException(feErrorEnum.INTERNAL_EXCEPTION, sqle.getMessage());
    } finally {
        closeConnection(con, ps, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [executeBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--)

```
ps.executeBatch();
```

instead of :

```
ps.executeUpdate();
```

**Note** that `executeBatch()` :

> **Returns
>   an array of update counts containing one element for each command in
>   the batch.** The elements of the array are ordered according to the
>   order in which commands were added to the batch.

so to check if your batch work fine or not you can use :

```
int[] count = ps.executeBatch();
```

---

And you have to put your batch between

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);//Disabling auto-commit mode

ps = con.prepareStatement(REMOVE_DATA_MAP);
for (int i = 0; i < packagedServiceIdList.size(); i++) {

    ps.setString(1, partnerId);
    ps.setString(2, packagedServiceIdList.get(i));
    ps.addBatch();
    gLogger.debug("query is: " + ps.toString());
}

int[] count = ps.executeBatch();//execute the batch

con.commit();//Commit the SQL statements
```

Comment: In my previous code i tried with ps.executeBatch();. Even that didn't work.

Comment: String REMOVE_CHANNEL_STATION_MAP = "DELETE FROM channel_station_map WHERE partner_id=? and packaged_service_id=? ";

Comment: What type of `partner_id` and `packaged_service_id`?

Comment: Both are strings.

Comment: are you sure I don't see any other problem in your code except this, but can you tell me what rdbms you are using?

Comment: there is no error or exception in the logs. and i have written a method for addition in the same way. That works well but deletion does not work.

Comment: @ShaliniLakshkar check my edit, you have to put your batch between `con.setAutoCommit(false);` and `con.commit();`